# Variable length differ in R

Tags: r

i'm performing Anova testing for my current datasets that has multiple columns which i am trying to loop to make things easier but it seems to me that i am always facing the same error called "variable lengths differ"

here is my code for the loop:

```
for(i in 5:125){
WL<- colnames(NB[i])
model <- lm(WL ~ Treatment , data = NB)
  if(!exists("aovNB")){
    aovNB<-anova(model)
  }
  if(exists("aovNB")){
    aovNB <- rbind(aovNB,anova(model))
  }
}
```

and i'm wondering if it is possible that way to store the column names into WL variable which i can use to read the multiple columns i have.

thanks if anyone could solve it. i'm using base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reformulate`/`as.formula` to create formula from strings. Also instead of rbinding the datasets in a loop store them in a list.

```
cols <- colnames(NB)[5:125]
result <- vector('list', length(cols))

for(i in seq_along(cols)){
  model <- lm(reformulate('Treatment', cols[i]) , data = NB)
  result[[i]] <- anova(model)
}
```

If needed you can combine them using `result <- do.call(rbind, result)`

Answer (score 0):

We may do this with `paste`

```
cols <- colnames(NB)[5:125]
result <- vector('list', length(cols))
for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
   result[[i]] <- anova(lm(as.formula(paste(cols[i], '~ Treatment')), data = NB))
 }
```